# How to use "<g:TabLayoutPanel" in UiBinder in "GWTP"?

Tags: uibinder, gwtp

I am using "GWTP" not "GWT", there no `RootLayoutPanel` to add `TabLayoutPanel` into it.

In Eclipse, i can generate MyPresenter, MyView & MyUiBinder.ui.xml files automatically.

So, in MyUiBinder.ui.xml, i have

```
 <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="mainTabPanel" barUnit="PX"  barHeight="60" width="100%" height="100%">
   <g:tab>
        <g:header>Welcome</g:header>
        <g:HTMLPanel height="100%" > Some more stuffs here
        </g:HTMLPanel>
   </g:tab>
 </g:TabLayoutPanel>
```

However, after ran, it only shows the Header of the Tab, I can't see any contents of HTMLPanel. But when set `height="600px"` for `TabLayoutPanel` then i can see, i don't want fixed height. I wants height of `TabLayoutPanel` to 100%.

So how to use `TabLayoutPanel` properly in UiBinder in GWTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** you will need `height="600px"`

**Long answer:** See [GWT TabLayoutPanel do not renders the graph content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777213/gwt-tablayoutpanel-do-not-renders-the-graph-content)

Comment: using TabPanel seems ok, i didn't see any Quirks in FFox, IE or Chrome?